# Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{N}{\cos nx}={1\over 2}+{1\over 2}\sum_{-N}^{N}e^{inx}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{N}{\cos nx}={1\over 2}+{1\over 2}\sum_{-N}^{N}e^{inx}$? I have gone through all the identities relating Fourier series and I can't seem to understand why. In this question, the assumption is that the functions are $2\pi$ periodic(In some places the initial assumption is that the functions are, for example 1- periodic and then the $2\pi$ is being placed within the function instead. I am sorry if you didn't understand what I meant. I am not native and find some things hard to express.). I could really use your help.

Comment: Should that be $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{-N}^N e^{in x}$?

Comment: So some answer claims.

Comment: Do you believe it shouldn't?

Comment: I believe it should be $\sum$ rather than $\int$.

Comment: I am so, so sorry. I am really not focused. I am sorry to have mislead you like that.

Comment: $\cos(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2}$

Comment: Thank you. It is now solved. Too bad the answer was deleted, I was about to accept it.